# Parallel load in a common table in teradata

Tags: teradata

```
I am loading data into my common table DB_TBLS.ACCOUNT in parralel for three process. To avoid     blocking i have created view as below on top of this base table.
But again i am getting blocking on the base table.

Replace View DB_VWS.S_ACCOUNT as locking row for access 
Select * From DB_TBLS.ACCOUNT where id = 1 ;

Replace View DB_VWS.T_ACCOUNT as locking row for access 
 Select * From DB_TBLS.ACCOUNT where id = 2 ;

Replace View DB_VWS.R_ACCOUNT as locking row for access 
Select * From DB_TBLS.ACCOUNT where id = 3 ;
```

Can anyone please help me in loading data in parallel in common table ?

Comment: What is the Primary Index of that table? How do you load? How many rows are you going to load? Why don't you use one of the existing Teradata load tools?

Comment: I am using bteq for this parallel load. We have almost 5-10K records. Primary index is combination of id and two more columns.

Comment: Use a single session with a high PACK factor. The maximum possible PACK depends on your input data, you might try a few hundred. This should run in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Stream Operator in the Teradata Parallel Transporter (TPT) utility provides the functionality which you require. According to TPT Reference Manual (14.10):

`The Stream operator, a consumer operator, emulates the Teradata TPump utility to perform high-speed parallel Inserts, Updates, Deletes, and Upserts in a near-real-time to one or more empty or preexisting Teradata Database tables without locking target tables.`